# Какого типа должна быть переменная?

Tags: java

В ходе работы программа получит на вход вот такое вот число 9999683411343521124
какого типа лучше сделать переменную, в которую запишется это число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от специфики задачи. [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) или возможно просто `String`.

Comment: Вообще это просто адишник экземпляра класса.
Вот думаю, с чем лучше работать - String или BigInteger

Comment: Тогда поясните специфику задачи. Какие операции вы собираетесь применять к вашим числам?

Comment: вообщем-то ничего особенного - только лишь использовать число как айдишник, т.е. доставать объект по этому айдишнику

Comment: @Stas0n: Тогда строки по идее должно быть за глаза достаточно.

Comment: да, вот тоже думаю...